# Java wrong output file (encoding)

Tags: java, file-io, encoding

I have some void functions that prints out to console. However, I had to write them to text file and that is why, I used

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(newFileOutputStream("Programoutput.txt"));
System.setOut(out);
```

in the beginning of my main function. However the output file after running the program contains some Chinese characters. Any idea why this happened? You can find my code below. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 (maybe affects).

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    path = args[0];
    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("Programoutput.txt"));
    System.setOut(out);
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    // Set up Commands to Array
    String[] commands = new String[numOfLines(path)];
    setUpArray(path, commands);
    // Build Memory
    int memorySize = Integer.parseInt(commands[0].split(" ")[1]);
    String replacement = commands[1].split(" ")[1];
    String searchStructure = commands[2].split(" ")[1];
    // Creating Data Structure Objects
    Queue memory = new Queue(memorySize);
    BST binaryTree = new BST();
    ModifiedQueue mq = new ModifiedQueue(memorySize);
    MaxHeapTree hTree = new MaxHeapTree(memorySize);
    if(replacement.equals("FIFO") && searchStructure.equals("BinarySearch")){
        fifoQueue(memory, binaryTree, commands);
    }else if(replacement.equals("PriorityQueue") && searchStructure.equals("BinarySearch")){
        priorityQueue(hTree, binaryTree, commands);
    }else if(replacement.equals("SecondChance") && searchStructure.equals("BinarySearch")){
        secondChanceQueue(mq, binaryTree, commands);
    }
    long endTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
    double totalTime = endTime/1e9;

    System.out.println("Elapsed time in seconds: " + totalTime);  
}
```

Comment: With which editor are you opening the output file? Can you open it with a hexeditor and look which hex values have the "chinese" characters? Maybe these are some control sequence characters.

Comment: Can you try to explicit set encoding for outputStream like `new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("Programoutput.txt"), false, "UTF-8")`? Is result the same? Which your sources files encoding?

Comment: I opened it just with gedit in ubuntu. But when i tried the to open it with online hex editor, it showed the desired output. How can i change it?

Comment: Yeah i tried with the code that you provided but it did not change.

Comment: @HabilGanbarli According the documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) the encoding of the platform is used. Yuriy Alevohin's code sets UTF-8 for the output encoding. What encoding do you need?

Comment: First of all, thank you all, when i changed the char encoding of source file to UTF-8 it worked.